# DataGridView without DataSource to XML string

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have some DataGridViews on a form, and would like to get a XML string from it.
But for some reason it gives "*Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException'*" at the point of return.
When I look inside the foreach rows, it has the data I have put in.
What is the problem here?

```
    public string DataGridViewToXML(DataGridView DGV)
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DGV.Columns) { DT.Columns.Add(col.Name); }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dRow = DT.NewRow();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) { dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value; }
            DT.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        return DT.DataSet.GetXml();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There is no DataSet for your DataTable `DT`.

Comment: Ok clear, so the way I populate the DataTable doens't create a DataSet. I've searched on the internet, still no solution to just save the data the user puts in the DataGridView, could not be so hard?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told as at what line it trows it but as i get it you copy all data from `DGV` to `DT` so you can parse `DataSet.GetXml();`?

If that is the case why you just do not do:

```
public string DataGridViewToXML(DataGridView DGV)
{
    return (DGV.DataSource as DataTable).DataSet.GetXml();
}
```

I know it doesn't solve your null error but why would you solve it when you have easier way of doing you command. Other way tell me at what line error drops and i will try explaining why it happens.

Comment: I don't have a .dataSource in this case